# Magento 2 how to use phtml jquery events on knockouts js component template?

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

I'm struggling trying to approach the following objective:

Use jquery events on a knockout js component template.

On phtml file I have my knockout js component like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="notification content-form">
    <?php //if($identificator == "port"):  ?>
      <div id="port-form" data-bind="scope:'port-form'">
      <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
      <?php if($hasSpouse): ?>
      <!-- ko template: template2 --><!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko template: template3 --><!-- /ko -->
      <?php endif; ?>
      <!-- ko template: template4 --><!-- /ko -->
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#port-form": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                  "components": {
                        "port-form": {
                            "component": "Vendor_Application/js/port-app-form",
                            "quote_data": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $data ?>,
                            "quantities": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $quantities ?>,
                            "states": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $states ?>
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have 4 different templates, at the bottom of phtml I try the following:

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $("#beneficiary-button").click(function(){
      alert("clicked!");
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

When I click the button #beneficiary-button it's not doing anything, my guess is because I can't reach knockoutjs templates, so I would need to require my jquery validations on knockoutjs component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will likely be your jQuery code being evaluated before the element is on the page, you can use event delegation to solve it.

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#beneficiary-button', function() {
      alert('Clicked');
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

You can swap `document` with the closest parent that is server-side rendered to improve performance slightly.

Although I would advise using Knockout to handle clicks and not jQuery as now you have two libraries to achieve the same thing and they can conflict.

Comment: thanks! yes I think I will use just Knockout to handle clicks.